# Adding an image in Android Studio?

Tags: android

How can I add an image to be permanently there? For example in the photo below, the Tinder logo is always at the top, and it has navigational buttons on it.

[image]

Comment: I'll do what the people that downvoted you should have done but didn't. Please check the [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the community have a few guidelines on how a good question should look, please have a look as it will help people help you.

Comment: Thank you, I wasnt aware

Answer (score 0):

This is known as the [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html), but if you didn't know that I suggest you study how [Android Layout](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) works first, otherwise you will just have a bunch of more doubts of how layouts works, it won't take long and will be very clarifying.